# Raise selection event (didSelectRowAtIndexPath) when subview of UITableViewCell is tapped

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I've created a custom UITableViewCell that includes a number of subviews.  In most cases I want the controller for the UITableViewCell to handle the events.  In one case I want the subview to simply pass on the event to the parent UITableViewCell which will cause it to invoke didSelectRowAtIndexPath on the assigned delegate.

To put it another way: I want the subview to become "event transparent" -- I want events to pass over / through it and register with the underlying cell.

Any suggestions?  In other languages I would raise an event.  New to Objective-C and Cocoa and haven't been able to google up an answer yet.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try setting your view's `userInteractionEnabled` property to `NO`.

This will make it ignore all touch events, and then the views under it will be able to catch these events.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of ways come to my mind:

I believe the translation for "raise an event" would be to send a notification, in which case you could look into `NSNotification` and `NSNotificationCenter`. Pretty simple.

Optionally, you could add a reference to an object that follows the `UITableViewDelegate` protocol to each cell, and when creating the cell, assigning that reference to the object that you want to handle that event, when the subview is tapped, send the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` message to that reference.

Personally I'd choose the second one, because I'm not a big fan of notifications.