# custom uitablviewcell does not call didSelectRowAtIndexPath in the controller

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I have a custom `UITableViewCell` completely written in code (no IB), it has an accessory button that simply calls `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` on the table view, and it works correctly and the method is called without problems.

However, when I tap on the cell itself (not on the accessory view) nothing being called, why ?

EDIT: the code is huge to put here ... however, the custom cell contains a ton of labels, couple images and scroll view ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a shot in the dark, but if each cell has many different objects on it (i.e. images, labels, etc) then it may not be working because those objects are what the user is hitting when they try to click a cell. Does the cell turn blue (indicate selection) at all? If not, try hiding/removing those objects for now and see if it works.

If that is the case, then what you may want to do is create an invisible cell or button that sits on top of the other objects and calls didSelectRowAtIndexPath from behind the scenes.

This should solve your problem:
[Raise selection event (didSelectRowAtIndexPath) when subview of UITableViewCell is tapped](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6420031/raise-selection-event-didselectrowatindexpath-when-subview-of-uitableviewcell)

Try setting your view's userInteractionEnabled property to NO.

This will make it ignore all touch events, and then the views under it will be able to catch these events. - Felipe Sabino

Comment: bull's eye ... but, is there a way to call didSelectRowAtIndexPath with the existence of these subviews ?

Answer (score 1):

You must post your code to understand what have you done...You have to check out this example to understand whether your code is correct or not...

http://www.edumobile.org/iphone/iphone-programming-tutorials/impliment-a-custom-accessory-view-for-your-uitableview-in-iphone/

Comment: @JAHelia check out that example.In that ,they did a call for another method for accessory view.If u want t to click cell also,then you can write code in didSelectRowAtPath method.

Answer (score 1):

I'd partially answer my question: the wide scroll view is preventing the cell from calling didSelectRowAtIndexPath, removing the scrollView will solve the problem, however, I want to call this method with the existence of the scrollView ... anyone got ideas would be highly appreciated ...